# What is your philosophy behind [tag:philosophy]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There is a popular tag [philosophy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy) which has no guidance/wiki yet. I am bit confused about it's usage. So, When should I use that tag? What type of questions should fall in the category of [philosophy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/philosophy)? Can I have some example?

I've also used this tag sometimes but not sure about it's clear and exact usage. So, I've asked this question.

Comment: Isn't it fairly clear?  It's for questions about Hindu philosophy - for instance, questions about the Vedanta school.  If you want examples of philosophy questions, take a look at my philosophy questions: http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bphilosophy%5D+user%3A36+is%3Aquestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!: Tag excerpt is created:

> Questions about Hindu Philosophy, which is divided into six main schools: Sankhya, Yoga, Nyaya, Vaiaeaika, Mimamsa and Vedanta.

For more Information related to Philosophy, I recommend visiting: [**Hinduism Philosophy**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_philosophy).

Comment: Hindu philosophy is not limited to the shatdarsanas. It encompasses any inquiry into the ultimate truth (I. E. Brahman) and includes the prasthana traya, inter alia.

Comment: @moonstar2001 If you have more clear idea for [tag:philosophy], then you can post better answer ; also welcome to edit tag-wikis.